# BlueStacks - Android Virtual Devices don't get assigned IP and port

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, bluestacks

I just installed `BlueStacks` latest version using the default configuration.
Then I ran the `Android SDK` command:

```
> adb devices
```

and I got:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

As you can see, the `BlueStacks` doesn't get an `IP` and `Port`.

I cannot deploy from `MSVS2015` to this `AVD` and I think that's the reason, because I also have `Genymotion AVD` installed which has an `IP` and `Port` and this is visible by the `MSVS2015`.

```
List of devices attached
192.168.189.101:5555    device
```

How can I make the `BlueStacks` get an `IP` and `Port` for the `AVD` and then deploy to it from `MSVS2015/Xamarin`?

Comment: when running the above command, I get: `unable to connect to emulator-5554:5555: cannot resolve host 'emulator-5554' and port 5555: No such host is known. (11001)`

Comment: Need more coffee...  `adb shell ifconfig` to get the ip address of the emulator, then `adb tcpip 6000` to map port 6000 to tcp, then `adb connect {ip}:6000` where {ip} is the ip address you got from `ifconfig`

Comment: What's your deployment error? You don't need to run adb over tcp  usually to do any deployment, it's required generally to run over wifi if you don't want to connect device with USB wire. As long as you are deploying from same host it's enough if you see device name in 'adb devices'

Comment: I don't get any deployment error because `MSVS2015` don't list that `BlueStacks AVD` under the available devices to deploy on. So I cannot deploy on that `AVD` and then I don't get any error on deployment.

Comment: @SushiHangover, when I run the command: `> adb shell ifconfig` on my windows console I get no outputs and nothing changes. Still not working.

Comment: Should it work? This seems like a player. Do they support "development mode"?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem, that the bluestacks AVD should be set in development mode. But under Settings I don't find that option. In my real device I can find it though.

Comment: You get the same output from `adb devices`, e.g. `emulator-5554   device` when using the Google emulators, so that does not necessarily mean that there is no ip address for the emulator. If I run `adb shell ifconfig` indeed the emulator does have an IP address. Have you contacted Bluestacks support? PS: Xamarin Android Player (deprecated) shows IP Address and Port with `adb devices` and uses the same backend as Genymotion, so I think this is just how the emulators name themselves to `adb`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: run `netstat -a` in your command prompt. If you see `127.0.0.1:5555 running`, then everything is okay, else disable your firewall. Then run `adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following did the trick: On the Bluestacks machine (assuming it is a Windows machine) run cmd as Administrator and type in:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress={ip.of.bluestacks.windows.machine} listenport=5555 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=5555
```

Now you can connect from remote machine using

```
adb connect {ip.of.bluestacks.windows.machine}:5555
```